# angular function Error: [$parse:syntax]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Error Message is

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.13/$parse/syntax?p0=list.type&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=9&p3=Fedit(%7B%7Blist.type%7D%7D%2C%7B%7Blist.id%7D%7D)&p4=list.type%7D%7D%2C%7B%7Blist.id%7D%7D)
    at Error (native)
    at http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:6:457
    at bb.throwError (http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:169:490)
    at bb.consume (http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:170:424)
    at bb.object (http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:177:474)
    at bb.primary (http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:169:121)
    at bb.unary (http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:175:273)
    at bb.multiplicative (http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:175:6)
    at bb.additive (http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:174:399)
    at bb.relational (http://127.0.1.1/AnjularJS/ng-Films/Scripts/Vendor/angular.min.js:174:263) <button ng-click="Fedit({{list.type}},{{list.id}})" class="btn btn-primary">
```

using the code is

```html
<tbody ng-repeat="list in lists">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <button ng-click="Fedit({{list.type}},{{list.id}})" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="Fdelete({{list.type}},{{list.id}})" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The function actually take the two Arguments in list array. but I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<tbody ng-repeat="list in lists">
 <tr>
  <td>                          
   <button ng-click="Fedit(list.type,list.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   <button ng-click="Fdelete(list.type,list.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope it helps.....!

Comment: Hi Alagu MS already I was try this it show no errors but in html page it show ng-click="Fedit(list.type, list.id)" but i need list.id value like 2 or 3.....

Comment: is working, not shown values in html but when function runs its take the values

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I only took out the brackets.

Like this: Fedit({{list.type}},{{list.id}}) --> Fedit(list.type,list.id)

Tanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link [$parse:syntax](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/error/$parse/syntax?p0=,&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=,460&p4=,460)

In my case this error is showing when I use `,` on angular expressions

Regards

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat has it's own scope and attribute binding as you have given does not work -{{list.type}} needs to be just list.type and {{list.id}} becomes list.id.

see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-repeat)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an extra space in angular expressions:

```
{{Student.Enrollment Date}}
```

The right one:

```
{{Student.EnrollmentDate}}
```